How do I find the highest sum of multiple cells in column A where the sum is based on multiple cells matching in column B in Google Sheets?
I deeply apologize for the title being unclear. It is difficult to explain what I am looking for in such a small amount of characters. To provide some background, see the table below for reference.



Column A
Column B




600
apple


-100
apple


-200
apple


500
orange


-100
orange


300
pear



I am looking for a single formula that will find the highest sum of values in column A that have matching values in column B. Per the table, apple has the highest individual value of 600 at A2. However, when summing apple's corresponding values in column A, 600 - 100 - 200 = 300. When performing the same calculations with orange, 500 - 100 = 400. Thus, I would like the formula to return 400 since it is greater than apple's 300.
At some point, I ended up with the following formula. After testing, I realize it is incorrect:
=SUM(FILTER(B2:B7,A2:A7=INDEX(A2:A7,MATCH(MAX(COUNTIF(A2:A7,A2:A7)),COUNTIF(A2:A7,A2:A7),0))))
It appears the above formula first finds the highest occurring fruit in column B and then sums it's corresponding values in column A afterwards. The solution I am looking for shouldn't care about the number of occurrences in column B.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

=index(query(A:B,"SELECT SUM(A), B WHERE NOT A IS NULL GROUP BY B ORDER BY SUM(A) DESC"),2)

Result:

Or
=index(sort(HSTACK(map(unique(B1:B6),lambda(a,sumif(B1:B6,a,A1:A6))),unique(B1:B6)),1,0),1)


For the most part, the second formula seems to work great! How do I change the formula so that "orange" is not displayed in the cell next to result?

Nevermind. I was able to figure out how to remove "orange" by removing the last parameter of the lambda function. Thanks a bunch!

As an alternative;
=MAX(INDEX(QUERY(A1:B, "Select Sum(A), B Group By B"),,1))
which calculates the Max of the first column of the query result.

Query the sum of column A while grouping by B. From the result of the previous query, query the maximum of sum of column A(Col2), while setting the label to a empty string:
=QUERY(
    QUERY(A:B, "Select B,sum(A) group by B"),
    "select max(Col2) label max(Col2) ''"
)

